# MSACCESS Report - Show or Hide "Group By Header"

Tags: ms-access, report

Goal - The report has calculated fields in the HEADER of the GROUP on Reinsurer

The goal is to only print this header when there is MORE THAN ONE "Issuing_Dealer_Name"

In the data, Corinne has 2 dealers. Therefore I want to print the HEADER of the GROUP on Reinsurer

Adam has 1 dealer. Therefore, don't print the Header of the Group on Reinsurer

Therefore, what code goes into the "On Format" event of this header?

Here's a link to a jpg of the data -
[View the Dataset](https://ibb.co/M2XhZwF)

Comment: Need a count of dealers associated with reinsurer. Could use a DCount() expression in textbox ControlSource. Then code would check that textbox: `Me.GroupHeader0.Visible = Me.tbxCount > 1` or the DCount() could be in VBA in place of Me.tbxCount reference.

Comment: I was able to implement your suggestion. However, the DCount() returns a number that is the total rows in the entire dataset. I need the number of DISTINCT dealer_names within this Group on section. 
The dataset has a line for every contract signed. A dealer could have 1 sale or many. Therefore the rowcount wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: So you need to build a query that aggregates dealer names by group. `SELECT DISTINCT Dealer, Reinsurer FROM table;`. Reference that query in the DCount for a count of dealers per reinsurer.

Answer (score 0):

The two suggestions above solved it. Thanks!

I resolved this by creating a make-table query with a select distinct clause. Then I referenced this new table in the DCount function. It works. Once I have time, I'd rather use an array to minimize report creation resources used. BTW, I created a table vs. query since the DCount would be called about 600 times.